# C# custom picturebox control

Tags: c#, bitmap, custom-controls, paint, picturebox

I work on a project where I need to constantly get bitmaps and draw them on a picturebox.

The idea is to draw a first initial bitmap, then retrive the rest of the bitmap and draw them above the initial one. (The first one still displayed in the picturebox, so I want to draw them  on the first bitmap).

I tried to design a custom control, to implement the `OnPaint` event, but the second time the event is fired, it draws the second `block` and completely conceals the image which had been drawn before.

```
public class RapidPictureBox: PictureBox
{
    public pictureBox1Control()
    {
        SetStyle(
          ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
          ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
          ControlStyles.UserPaint |
          ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }

     public Bitmap block = null;
     public int x = 0, y = 0;
     protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
     {
         e.Graphics.DrawImage(block, x, y);
     }
 }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    RapidPictureBox pictureBox1 = new RapidPictureBox();
    pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    Controls.Add(pictureBox1);

    pictureBox1.block = new Bitmap("3.png"); //first initial image

    pictureBox1.block = new Bitmap("2.png"); //draw on the initial one.
}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong in the code. I use the `e` EventArgs to draw a new block everytime I need but it seems the new drawing compeletly hides the previous bitmap.

Comment: You have marked `Shlomi's` answer as your accepted answer. How is that fixing your problem? Any image you draw with graphics object you get using pictureBox1.CreateGraphics() will be wiped immediately without redrawing it again in OnPaint overridden method.

Comment: @user12572 no, without a custom control ,if i'll just use picturebox and create a graphics object from it,it would draw on top of the current image.You can see for yourself.at least here i only draw one block everyime and not the whole image.

Comment: Got it! So you need to draw second image repeatedly but no need to draw first image. Nice :)

Comment: @user12572 not only the second,it's ,many small images i'm getting but yeah :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a graphics object from the picturebox,then redraw it over the current image

```
initial =new Bitmap("test.png");
pictureBox1.Image = initial;
var graphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics(); //create a graphic objec
graphics.DrawImage(block, x,y);//that's the second method
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is overlay the new image on previous image.
Let's say there is a primary image (first image) and you want to print next image(overlapping image) on that same primary image. Use following method to do that.

```
private Bitmap GetOvelappedImages(Bitmap primaryImage, Bitmap overlappingImage)
{
 //create graphics from main image
 using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(primaryImage))
 {
    //draw other image on top of main Image
     g.DrawImage(overlappingImage, new Point(0, 0));
 }
 return primaryImage;
}
```

then set this new image to pictureBox1.block.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    RapidPictureBox pictureBox1 = new RapidPictureBox();
    pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    Controls.Add(pictureBox1);

    pictureBox1.block = GetOverlappedImages(new Bitmap("3.png"),new Bitmap("2.png")); //draw on the initial one.
}
```

That should work for you.

**Note:** You should dispose images after they are used.

**Update:**
You need to redraw whole image because, OnPaint is called only when current image shown on picture box needs to be redrawn. 
*The OnPaint method is overridden to repaint the image each time the form is painted; otherwise the image would only persist until the next repainting.*
Read documentation for OnPaint [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Nice, this is essentially the code for the basic form of the idea at the bottom of my answer

Comment: @user12572 i didn't want such a solution like this... it's gonna rip my performance :( i'm getting somthing like 60~70 little blocks per second,redrawing 60~70 times the full bitmap would just..damn.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are not adding pictures to the control you are replacing them.

**Side Note**: With the code you have you are not disposing of the `Bitmap` objects set in the `PictureBox`es image and so this could cause memory leaks.

You can create a similar control `LayeredPictureBox`. This will get all of the images and draw them on top of each other. It will have poor performance and the images will need to have transparency to look layered but you get the idea:

```
public class LayeredPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    public LayeredPictureBox()
    {
        SetStyle(
          ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
          ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
          ControlStyles.UserPaint |
          ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }

     public List<Bitmap> blocks = new List<Bitmap>();
     public int x = 0, y = 0;
     protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
     {
         foreach (Bitmap block in blocks)
         {
             e.Graphics.DrawImage(block, x, y);
         }
     }
 }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    RapidPictureBox pictureBox1 = new RapidPictureBox();
    pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    Controls.Add(pictureBox1);

    pictureBox1.blocks.Add(new Bitmap("3.png")); //first initial image

    pictureBox1.blocks.Add(new Bitmap("2.png")); //draw on the initial one.
}
```

Another option is to merge all of the images together on adding them and then just drawing that image into the PictureBox.

Comment: actually what youv don is that on every refresh the control will draw the entire list...that's definetley bad. i'll tell here the short idea:it's for a screen sharing project,where i recieve a full deksopt bitmap from a socket,and then i retrieve many small bitmap blocks from the socket and need to update  them in a picturebox-which would provide an updated desktop image. -

Comment: @Slashy I know it is bad, I said that, this is a very basic idea for what you want to achieve. I will not write the code for you just point you in the right direction to come to the solution yourself. And that is to merge the images before drawing them on the PictureBox.

Comment: @ TheLethalCoder look the updated comment :).
now i know i could create `Graphics` object from the picturebox,and draw every block i get without creating the user control-but the `Picturebox.CreateGraphics` caused some drawing problems..so i prefered to use the `OnPaint` event///

Comment: @Slashy Always use the `OnPaint` events graphics object where appropriate as you are doing. But the answer is still the same the images need to be merged or drawn on top of each other one by one.

Comment: no way..isn't it posibble to draw on an already existing image?:(

Comment: @Slashy yes that's what the very basic implementation above is doing, or you could just merge the images and draw that one, either way the idea is the same

Comment: @Slashy You'd probably also want to store the images in a `List<KeyValuePair<Bitmap, Point>>` so that the points correspond correctly to the images. In a list this way and not a dictionary so that it is ordered.

Comment: look... I do not usually argue when a code works,but since it's kind of a real time program,it has to be fast and efficient as much as possibble.drawing the whole imags,or merging the secondary and primary bitmap and drawing the entire initial  bitmap again-seems really not efficient too me :(
do you agree drawing the whole bitmap again(as your second suggestion) while only a small region changed is really unnecessary?i'll edit the question to show you how i would do it with the `CreateGraphics` method(which i dont want to use :))

Comment: @Slashy All that method does is draw on top of the image, exactly what I've shown above. What happens in your method when it needs redrawing? The second image disappears because it is not in the paint event. If you want you can only redraw parts of the image but that becomes complicated and out of the scope of my answer which is essentially layer them.